# How to remove only starting and ending special character from a string?

Tags: java

I want to remove only the starting special character i.e. " and ending special character ".
The given input string is

```
String input= "\"This#string%contains^special*characters&.\"";
```

The expected output is

```
String output= "This#string%contains^special*characters&.";
```

Can any one help me how to do this using regex or any other way to remove only starting and ending special character only from the input string in java.

Comment: javascript != java

Comment: @Yousaf since the datatype is mentioned, i think its java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a regex approach:

```
String input= "\"This#string%contains^special*characters&.\"";
String output = input.replaceAll("^[^A-Za-z0-9]|[^A-Za-z0-9]$", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
This#string%contains^special*characters&.
```

Comment: But here If i will pass "This#string%contains^special*characters&.;" as an input then getting an output as "This#string%contains^special*characters&." which is removing ; from last. I don't want to remove any other special character except  \" in starting and \" at the end. If other special character present then it will just ignore. Could you please help me to get regex for this scenario.